# window.width() 1730. хотя браузер развернут в fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery

консоль выдает 1730 ширину окна браузера в фулл скрине. 
screen.width выдает 1920. куда пропали 190 пикселей?

`document.onload=alert(window.innerWidth)` вообще 1745 пикселей.

также отличаются показания этих двух значений

```
console.log( $( window ).outerWidth(true) )  //=1745

    console.log(window.outerWidth)    //=1920
```

из-за чего такое расхождение в значениях?

Comment: Покажите скриншот проблемного окна на всякий случай

Comment: @andreymal прошу прощения, но зачем? как контент сайта повлияет на размеры окна браузера?

Comment: А я спрашиваю про окно браузера, а не про контент. Вот например на нём можно было бы сразу увидеть масштаб 110%

Comment: @andreymal, я и так сразу догадался))

Comment: @Qwertiy меня очень смущает строчка `console.log(window.outerWidth) //=1920`, которую вроде бы так сходу нельзя объяснить масштабом, поэтому я предпочёл сразу не догадываться

Answer (score 0):

Просто у тебя масштаб страницы 110%.

Comment: да, так и есть. но почему масштаб страницы влияет на размеры окна браузера?

Comment: @андрейпупкин, а почему вы решили, что он не должен влиять на размер если происходит увеличение или уменьшение? Тут и ежу понятно, что влияет.

Comment: @And согласился бы полностью, если бы вычислял document.width

Comment: @андрейпупкин, дак изменяется то `document` а не `window`.

Comment: @And читаем внимательно заголовок. если меняется document, то почему размеры window не верные? и почему JS  правильно определяет, даже с учетом масштаба, а jquery - нет?

Comment: @андрейпупкин, вы сначала определитесь, в комментах одно в заголовке другое в вопросе третье.